# how to show number one by one

Tags: jquery, sequence, each

I have got this set of code here.

```
var qnum=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

$(":button").click(function () {
    if
    {
       ........
    }
    else
    {
        .......
    }
});


 jQuery.each(qnum , function(index, value){
            $("#question").html("Question " + index + "/10");
        });
```

My goal is to run a quiz. Each time the user answer a question, be it wrong or right, the question number increase by 1 till it reaches question 10.

How do I make it so that the show number show 1 by 1 after another.

Because for now, I put the code in, it run from 1 all the way to 10 without showing 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the current value with the `$("#question").html()` and then make it the `html` of `#question`.

```
        jQuery.each(qnum , function(index, value){
             $("#question").html($("#question").html() + " Question " + index + "/10");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do change the text in the click handler

```
var qnum = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    counter = 0;

$(":button").click(function () {
    if {........
    } else {.......
    }

    $("#question").html("Question " + qnum[counter++] + "/10");
});
```

---

Actually there is no need to have an array

```
var counter = 0;

$(":button").click(function () {
    if {........
    } else {.......
    }

    $("#question").html("Question " + (counter++) + "/10");
});
```